# C: How do you handle for no user input for scanf?

Tags: c, exception, user-input, scanf

Dear fellow Stackoverflowers,

How do you handle for 0 user input?

For example, if the user enters " " or just presses ENTER, how do you handle for that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

   printf("> \n");
   char string[129];
   int i = 0, length = 0, flag = 0;

   printf("Input a string: ");
   scanf("%128s", string);
   if(strlen(string) != 0) {
      printf("%s\n", string);
   } else {
      printf("Please enter at least one argument.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf()`, use `fgets()` and it should be easy,

Comment: Ah ok! I'll give that a try and report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving this with `scanf()` is probably impossible and I have no interest in finding out whether it's possible because this solution

```
#include <stdio.h> /* For fgets(), fprintf() and printf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For EXIT_FAILURE */
#include <ctype.h> /* For isspace() */

int
please_enter_at_least_one_argument()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Please enter at least one argument\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int
main(void)
{
    char string[130];

    printf("> \n");
    printf("Input a string: ");
    if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin) == NULL)
        return please_enter_at_least_one_argument();
    else
    {
        char *pointer;

        pointer = string;
        while (isspace((unsigned char) *pointer) != 0)
            pointer++;
        if (*pointer == '\0')
            return please_enter_at_least_one_argument();
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

solves the problem and is simple very easy to understand.

Please note that the first `please_enter_at_least_one_argument()` might not be correct because `fgets()` might return `NULL` if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (*Or on windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>*) and also when an error occurs. But to find out how to handle that you should probably read [man `fgets(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help sir!

Comment: Minor: In original code, input could be 128 letters and then a `'\n'`.  With this code, typical input would be limited to 127 letters and a `'\n'`.  When using `fgets()` vs. `scanf("%...s"`, best to use a +1 size buffer: `char string[129+1];`

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()`, regarding the `%s` conversion specifier,

> `s` Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

and regarding the steps for execution of a conversion specifier

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.

So, unless a non-whitespace character is there in the input stream, it will wait. No *matching* will take place.

Also, it's very important that you check the return value of `scanf()` and family to ensure that the scanning is success.

That said, `int main()` should be `int main(void)` at least to conform to the standards.

Comment: How may one do that?

Comment: @MsSingularity do what?

Comment: Handle white space characters

Comment: @MsSingularity I don't understand. What is there to handle, if you have only pressed enter?

Comment: @MsSingularity You can use `int r = scanf("%128[^\n]", string); if(r == 1) /* Something was entered */ else if(r == 0) /* Enter key was pressed without any input */ else /* EOF was entered or some input error happened */` Note that you might need to remove the `\n` (or clear the `stdin`) too.

Comment: This answer omits "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier" which is essentially OP's problem.  `"%s"` first matches and discards leading whitespace, like `'\n'`, and does not at that point.

Comment: @chux updated the answer to include the relevant part. Thanks.:)